# DuplicateFlagError when running Google or-tools TSP constraint solver on multiple graphs

Tags: python, google-api, or-tools, constraint-programming, gflags

I'm using Google's [ortools.constraint_solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp#or-tools) to find solutions to the Traveling Salesman Problem. [As seen here.](https://code.google.com/p/or-tools/source/browse/trunk/examples/python/tsp.py) Everything works as expected when I run the program on one set of points.

Now that I got that working, *I'm attempting to solve the TSP for multiple sets of points*, by looping over all the sets and calling the the constraint solver on each set.

I have the below code re-defining the [gflag](http://gflags.github.io/gflags/) [`tsp_size`](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/tsp.py) depending on the size of a particular problem (not all sets are the same size):

```
gflags.DEFINE_integer('tsp_size', len(points), 'Size of Traveling Salesman Problem instance.')
```

Again, it works when there is only one set being specified, but upon running it for the second set, I get the error: **`gflags.DuplicateFlagError: The flag 'tsp_size' is defined twice.`**

How can I make separate instances of the constraint solver within the same run of a program, considering I have multiple graphs?

Comment: You may want to re-read [ask].

Comment: @boardrider Could you explain your distaste for the question? I see you haven't made any significant contributions to the site yet; maybe you're misunderstanding what is considered acceptable? :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by importing the module at the start of each iteration, then deleting it in [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules).

This gives me a new instance of the constraint solver for each set, with gflag config values specific to that set's size :)

```
for graph in graphs:
    import shp
    shp.run(graph)
    del sys.modules['shp']
```

**EDIT:**

The above code was giving me issues, because `shp.py` wasn't being run as main. I ended up getting this to work with:

```
from subprocess import call

# graph_files is a collection of filenames each referencing graph txt files I'm using.    
for fn in graph_files:
    call(["python", "shp.py", fn])
```

*Use `subprocess.Popen` to do this asynchronously.*

Hope this helps someone.